# source IP using AKS azure internal load balancer

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I am creating internal load balancer like below

```yaml
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: alts
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
  labels:
    k8s-app: nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    k8s-app: nginx
  type: LoadBalancer
```

[image]

But the issue is my app (APP in image) is not able to get the private IP of VM (Original source) it is getting the source as a load balancer.

Pls suggest an answer or workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest two approaches. In one of my clusters, I used exernalTrafficPolicy=Local but as explained in [this article](https://blog.getambassador.io/externaltrafficpolicy-local-on-kubernetes-e66e498212f9), doing this just happened to keep the source IP. Alternatively, you may look at the X-Forwarded-For header in your app.

More info: https://medium.com/pablo-perez/k8s-externaltrafficpolicy-local-or-cluster-40b259a19404

Comment: Thanks, `exernalTrafficPolicy=Local` worked.